# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list, when running babel-node on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, babeljs

I am trying to run server.js file (node-express server) using babel-node using following command

```
>nodemon ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node src/server.js
```

This throws the error

```
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^    
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

content of babel-node script is

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*|*MINGW*|*MSYS*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../@babel/node/bin/babel-node.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/../@babel/node/bin/babel-node.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

Few answers suggest on windows we should run babel-node.cmd instead of babel-node so i tried so

```
>nodemon --delay 1 ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node.cmd src/server.js
```

but then i ran into this error

```
@ECHO off
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Content in babel-node.cmd

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
CALL :find_dp0

IF EXIST "%dp0%\node.exe" (
  SET "_prog=%dp0%\node.exe"
) ELSE (
  SET "_prog=node"
  SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
)

"%_prog%"  "%dp0%\..\@babel\node\bin\babel-node.js" %*
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /b %errorlevel%
:find_dp0
SET dp0=%~dp0
EXIT /b
```

Comment: Does `nodemon --exec ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node src/server.js` work?

Comment: @loganfsmyth No even that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Though I couldn't find the best solution, I managed to find a workaround to the problem by using babel-watch.

```
"dev": "babel-watch src/server.js",
```

It watch files for changes & restart server if any change occurs.